# Kubernetes: Cassandra(stateful set) deployment on GCP

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

Has anyone tried deploying Cassandra (POC) on GCP using kubernetes (not GKE). If so can you please share info on how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented cassandra on kubernetes. Please find my deployment and service yaml files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9042
  selector:
    app: cassandra
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
  labels:
    app: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
      containers:
      - name: cassandra
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v12
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: intra-node
        - containerPort: 7001
          name: tls-intra-node
        - containerPort: 7199
          name: jmx
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cql
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
           cpu: "500m"
           memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - nodetool drain
        env:
          - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
            value: 512M
          - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
            value: 100M
          - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
            value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
            value: "K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_DC
            value: "DC1-K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
            value: "Rack1-K8Demo"
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cassandra-data
          mountPath: /cassandra_data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "fast"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for deploying the kubenetes and Cassandra on GCP VMs using pd-ssd. do you have any working service yaml for it?

Answer (score 2):

You could start by looking at [IBM's Scalable-Cassandra-deployment-on-Kubernetes](https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/deploy-a-scalable-apache-cassandra-database-on-kubernetes/).

For seeds discovery you can use a headless service, similar to this [Multi-node Cassandra Cluster Made Easy with Kubernetes](http://node.mu/2015/09/18/multi-node-cassandra-cluster-made-easy-with-kubernetes/).

Some difficulties:

- [fast local storage for K8s is still in beta](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/); of course, you can use what k8s already has; there are [some users reporting](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/578d5f801cbf2d845c6ef2941149ee1065ef33d09400d08067ac2d53@%3Cuser.cassandra.apache.org%3E) that they use Ceph RBD with 8 C* nodes each of them having 2TB of data on K8s.
- at some point in time you will realize that you need a C* operator - here is some good startup - [Instaclustr's Cassandra Operator](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-operator) and [Pantheon Systems' Cassandra Operator](https://www.pipersgates.net/2018/10/23/cassandra-operator-for-kubernetes/)
- you need a way to [scale in gracefully stateful applications](https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/graceful-scaledown-of-stateful-apps-in-kubernetes-2205fc556ba9) (should be also covered by the operator; this is a solution if you don't want an operator, but you still need to use a controller).

You could also check the [Cassandra mailing list,](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@cassandra.apache.org:lte=18M:kubernetes) since there are people there already using Cassandra over K8s in production.

Answer (score 0):

Use Helm:

On Mac:

```
brew install helm@2
brew link --force helm@2
helm init
```

To Avoid Kubernetes Helm permission Hell:
from: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2224:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
```

## Cassandra

### incubator:

```
helm repo add https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/cassandra

helm install --namespace "cassandra" -n "cassandra" incubator/cassandra
helm status "cassandra"
helm delete  --purge "cassandra"
```

### bitnami:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

helm install --namespace "cassandra" -n "my-deployment" bitnami/cassandra
helm status "my-deployment"
helm delete  --purge "my-deployment"
```