# How to deploy my Cassandra cluster with Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, cluster-computing, coreos

I have tried to install Cassandra on my Kubernetes cluster. After executing the commands

```
kubectl apply -f Cassandra-service.yaml
```

and

```
kubectl apply -f cassandra-statefulset.yaml
```

I have no errors, but the three Cassandras pods are not setting up.

When I execute

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

the result is that a pod called `Cassandra-0` is not ready. I expected that the Cassandra pods would be already set up.

This is my `cassandra-statefulset.yaml` file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/cassandra/cassandra-statefulset.yaml

I expect there to be three Cassandra pods but there is only one in the pending state:

[image]

Here is the result of the previous command:

[image]

Comment: To be able to get more details can you: 1)Post you cassandra-statefulset.yaml 2)Post the result of `kubectl describe statefulset Cassandra` 3)Check if there are any errors when you see the logs of Cassandra with `kubectl logs Cassandra-0`

Comment: You can use the helm chart as described in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63916180/1447071

Answer (score 1):

What Kubernetes environment do you use? Do you use Minikube?

It seems that cluster cannot create PersistentVolumeClaim. Maybe `StorageClass` configuration doesn't suit your cluster.

Also example Cassandra deployment contains:

```
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
```

So, your cluster should has free 1.5cpu and ~3Gb.

On my opinion, it's better and easier to configure Helm charts for infrastructure deployments, for example - https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/cassandra

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are insufficient resources on minikube config so try to delete, reconfigure and start minikube, then deploy cassandra again.

**Note**: *minikube delete* will **delete all the k8s cluster** configured, be caferul.

```
minikube delete
minikube config set cpus 4
minikube config set memory 5120
minikube start
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/cassandra/cassandra-service.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/cassandra/cassandra-statefulset.yaml
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/